# layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" is broken in RTL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, right-to-left

I have a layout, which supports RTL. It looks fine in preview in Android studio and on device in default locale, but is broken in Arabic locale. There is an image on start, button on end and two texts in between.

Here's how it is designed and looks like in preview:
[image: Layout preview]

For some reason both button and image are placed at the end in Arabic locale. So, texts have no room and are not displayed, but view height is much larger than expected.

[image: Layout on device]

Here's how it looks like in LayoutInspector

[image: Layout Inspector]

What can be wrong with it?
I use databinding, if it does matter. This layout is placed in separate file and included with `include` tag

Here's the layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_med"
>
    <!-- Avatar image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        tools:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

    <!-- Call button -->
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:text="@string/call"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_pink"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_med"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_med"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            />

    <!-- Name-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_med"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_med"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/call"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/avatar"
    />

    <!-- Phone-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_med"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_med"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/call"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/avatar"        
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the API version of the device you are running on?

Comment: I have devices on 6.0 and 8.1

Answer (score 1):

I think that you had some missing constraints and you had some fixed size on your views.

What I did was to create a horizontal chain to all 3 views, make them the same height (exept the textViews with half the height of the other views) and it all worked out fine, here is what I did :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[2]" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" /
```

And here is how the row looks:

[image]

Comment: Well, in your example that would be the white squered box near "Ahmed" textView and the phone number.

Comment: what is it for? Just for placing others?

Comment: yes, it is just for placing another image, I saw that in your design  (the image) you had an image so I gave an example with an image. hope this was helpful.